# Google Maps v3: plot different sets of markers

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to plot on a google map a set of fixed markers and a marker for the user position. For these two sets of markers I would like to use a different image for the marker, however something weird is happening: when loading the page, the "fixed" markers get plotted properly but then immediately one disappears (the last one in the array) and then the user position shows up. In addition, the first fixed location gets the user location marker image, and the user positioning marker gets the image of the fixed markers. Ideally, the locations in the array will be plotted entirely (all 4) and with red_dot.png image on the marker, and the user positioning with the bluedot_retina.png on the marker.

It's really strange and I am struggling figuring out what is the root cause. Appreciate any help with this issue. thanks!

```
<script>

      var locations = [
            ['location a', 37.60756088, -122.42793323],
            ['location b', 37.759736, -122.426957],
            ['location c', 37.752950, -122.438458],
             ['location d', 37.763128, -122.457942]
          ];
      var map;
      var i;
      var marker;
      var google_lat = 37.757996;
      var google_long = -122.404479;
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(google_lat, google_long);

      //google.maps.visualRefresh = true;  

      function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 12,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


      var image_dot = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
          'images/red_dot.png',
          null, // size
          null, // origin
          new google.maps.Point( 8, 8 ), // anchor (move to center of marker)
          new google.maps.Size( 8, 8 ) // scaled size (required for Retina display icon)
      );

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              flat: true,
              position: myLatlng,
              icon: image,
              optimized: false,
              map: map,
              visible: true,
              title: 'I might be here'
        });

        setMarkers(map, locations);
      } //initialize();


      function setMarkers(map, locations) {

          for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          var beach = locations[i];
          var myLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng1,
            icon: image_dot,
            map: map
          });
        }
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

        var Tdata;
         var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
          'images/bluedot_retina.png',
          null, // size
          null, // origin
          new google.maps.Point( 8, 8 ), // anchor (move to center of marker)
          new google.maps.Size( 17, 17 ) // scaled size (required for Retina display icon)
       );
        var userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({icon: image});

        //var userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({icon: 'images/bluedot_retina.png'});

        $.ajax({
                method : "GET",
                url: "get_location.php",
                success : function(data){
                    Tdata=JSON.parse(data);
                   // console.log(data.lat);
                    console.log(Tdata.lat);
                    myFunction();
                }
        });

        function myFunction(){
                var interval = setInterval(function() { 
                    $.get("get_location.php", function(Tdata) {
                        var JsonObject= JSON.parse(Tdata);
                        google_lat = JsonObject.lat;
                        google_long = JsonObject.long;
                        console.log(google_lat, google_long);  
                        // $('#data').html('google_lat, google_long');
                        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(google_lat, google_long);
                        //marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
                        userMarker.setPosition(myLatlng);
                        userMarker.setMap(map);
                        //map.setCenter(myLatlng);
                    });
                }, 1000);
        }

  </script>
```

Comment: just make fiddel or plunker so we can take a look.

Comment: I am still running it on a local server so it wont work, but here you go: http://embed.plnkr.co/zYI2F8VkiR47c03SOSBj/preview

Comment: image_dot is defined in initialize function and you have used in setmarker function, And plunker is not working since there are local host file import in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`marker` is a global variable.  You are using it for both all of your locations and your user's position marker.  Don't do that, assign unique (or local) names to the two classes of markers.

```
var Tdata;
var userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({icon: URL/to/custom/icon/for/user});
$.ajax({
    method : "GET",
    url: "get_location.php",
    success : function(data){
       Tdata=JSON.parse(data);
       // console.log(data.lat);
       console.log(Tdata.lat);
       myFunction();
    }
});

function myFunction(){
   var interval = setInterval(function() { 
     $.get("get_location.php", function(Tdata) {
        var JsonObject= JSON.parse(Tdata);
        google_lat = JsonObject.lat;
        google_long = JsonObject.long;
        console.log(google_lat, google_long);  
        // $('#data').html('google_lat, google_long');
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(google_lat, google_long);
        userMarker.setPosition(myLatlng);
        userMarker.setMap(map);
        map.setCenter(myLatlng);
     });
   }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but the fixed markers are not :( I updated the code above, any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the fixed markers are not (working)"?  The code I posted shouldn't have affected them.  Did you change that code?